# OpenCL vloadn vs casting

Tags: opencl, vectorization

I optimize algorithms using OpenCL and I want to vectorise the kernel.
Is `vloadn / vstoren` slower then a simple cast to needed vector in case of aligned data?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `vloadn / vstoren` does not provide faster access. It only provides helper functionality to access the memory.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf

The spec is your firend.

Basically the only difference between casting and vloadn is that vloadn allows you to perform unaligned loads (unaligned to the vector size, the primitive must be aligned). If you perform simple cast to float4 the pointer must be aligned to 4*sizeof(float) boundary. If you perform vloadn for float4 the pointer must be aligned to sizeof(float) boundary.

So one might expect the pure cast to be faster as it does not have to check for alignment at all, and in no case whatsoever could the pure cast be slower, unless the implementation is bugged.

tl;dr: vloadn is probably slower than direct cast in case of aligned data.